# Adding and Removing active from class with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm beginner with react and trying to add/remove active class using useState & onClick, and the issue is that it works for all at the same time, and dunno how to make it on the pressed one. I want to know how to do it, and how to remove the active class from the other one as well.

Here is my code.

```
const [isActive, setisActive] = useState('');
const handClick = e => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    const currTarget = e.currentTarget;
    if(currTarget.className === "btn btn-primary active")
    {
        currTarget.classList.remove(setisActive("active"));
    } 
    else {
        currTarget.classList.add(setisActive("active"));
    }     
}
```

my navbar code

```
<div id="navbarlinks" className="d-flex justify-content-end me-5 pe-4">
                <button id="homebtn" onClick={handClick} className={"btn btn-primary " +  isActive}><a href="#" className="text-decoration-none text-white">Home</a></button>
                <button id="aboutbtn" onClick={handClick} className={"btn btn-primary " + isActive}><a href="#" className="text-decoration-none text-white">About Us</a></button>
                <button id="shopbtn" onClick={handClick} className={"btn btn-primary " + isActive}><a href="#" className="text-decoration-none text-white">Shop</a></button>
                <button id="contactbtn" onClick={handClick} className={"btn btn-primary " + isActive}><a href="#" className="text-decoration-none text-white">Contact Us</a></button>
            </div>
```

I tried to use for loop and many other things but nothing worked with me, So could anyone help? and thanks in advance :)

Comment: `setisActive(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you need, I think you are over complicating things by using useState for that since you could simply remove `active` from all of the `.btn-primary` elements.

```
const handClick = e => {
     const currTarget = e.currentTarget;   
     // disable all 
     document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary').forEach( btn => 
     btn.classList.remove('active'))
     currTarget.classList.add('active');  
}`
```